# When multi-classing, can you always select any spell from either spell list, as long as you have the correct level slots to use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

Apologies if this is a duplicate (or just common knowledge) but I found it hard coming up with a way to search for this succinctly enough to get a definitive answer and I haven't really played a spellcaster before.

If I have a warlock level 5, the warlock has slots of 3rd level. If I then put my next level into a sorcerer. Can I select sorcerer spells of up to level 3, or can I only select sorcerer spells of up to level 1 (i.e. the sorcerer level). I understand how spell slots are added between classes etc, I'm just not sure of this one thing. I had a look at the multi-classing section but either didn't see it or didn't understand it when I did see it.

Comment: It's certainly not common knowledge and it took me a while to find the duplicates, so this question is probably a fine addition to the site, helping people find the right answers. :)

Comment: @Erik Thank you for your comment. "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class" That's the part I was missing I think! A shame, but it makes sense. Again, thank you for pointing that out, I would have not thought to click on that question to attempt to find the answer to mine.